# Create multiple dynamic excel files in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, dynamic, ssis

I am creating a SSIS package, in which I am trying to create multiple dynamic excel files with 2 worksheets in each file. I can do this by using foreach loop container and flat files but I am not able to do this with excel files. I am able to create a dynamic file but each time the loop runs instead of creating new file it just overwrites the existing excel file. But the same approach works by using flat files.

For Flat files destination I am changing the file extension to .xls so it forcefully creates dynamic excel files.

The for each loop container is configured as foreach ADO Enumerator with the ADO object as a source variable which I have created to store all my distinct supplier numbers for which each separate excel file needs to be created.

I have a sql task connecting to my foreach loop container which provides the distinct list of suppliers from the table.

Comment: You haven't given us any of the pertinent information to be able to help you. How have you configured your foreach loop? How have you configured your dynamic excel file name? How are you resetting your excel file name?

Comment: @digital.aaron I have edited my question. I hope I have tried to explain it in a more better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still trying to do something similar to this can use the below link for reference.

http://www.rafael-salas.com/2006/12/import-header-line-tables-_116683388696570741.html

I was able to create multiple dynamic excel files by following it.